# windows phone intercept the http stream and redirect it to a proxy address

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

hi i'm working with windows phone 7 platform and the application provides an optimization service for mobile 3G (compression image, sound, video) same principle as onavo   ( http://bloguedegeek.net/2011/05/11/onavo-mise-a-lessai-du-compresseur-de-donnees-cellulaires/ )
.All i mean compression is done a proxy server the problem how to intercept the http stream and redirect it to the proxy address.

Is there someone who can give useful information.